# Kernel "Умирает" когда создаю объект spacy.load("en)

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

Итак, я пишу проект на Питоне, в нем я хочу работать с лингвистикой и для этого импортировал модуль spacy...Проблема в том, что когда я пытаюсь его использовать, Python прекращает работу и kernel умирает. Вот мой код до использования spacy, он исключений никаких не кидает:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Дальше я добавляю строчку nlp = spacy.load("en") в конце, и прога крашается...

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пробовали запускать напрямую, не через jupyter?

Comment: Что есть в логе jupyter'a?

Comment: Да, на PyCharm говорит Process finished with exit code -1073740791 (0xC0000409). Visual studio Python просто просит перезапустить и не работает... Когда гуглил ошибку Pycharm'a, сказали, что они  откатили драйвера и заработало, но я не хочу откатывать)

Comment: В логу jupyter просто много рестартов Kernel'a. Скрин нужен?

Comment: @Philippe, укажите пожалуйста версии Python, Pycharm и особенно Spacy

Comment: @MaxU Python 3.5, Pycharm 2017.1.2, spaCy 1.8.2

Comment: @Philippe, попробуйте загрузить `spacy` __до того__ как будете читать данные в DataFrame (кстати - он большой?). Возможно вым не хватает памяти

Comment: @MaxU Я убрал загрузку файла и оставил только import'ы и spacy.load("en"), исход тот-же... .csv файл весит 60 Мб

Comment: @Philippe, 60MB - это мелочи... Вероятно придется копаться с драйверами - у меня других идей нет...